# Time-complexity of nested for loop

Tags: algorithms, big-o

I have loops like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        sum += 1;
    }
}
```

It's O(n * ), but I'm not sure what the j < i loop is.

I have some tests that I ran,

```
n = 10, runs = 45

n = 20, runs = 190

n = 40, runs = 780

n = 80, runs = 3160

n = 10, runs = 12720
```

It seems to be converging onto .5*n^2, but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: On CS.SE: [Big O: Nested For Loop With Dependence](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/4590/big-o-nested-for-loop-with-dependence) says its O(n^2).

Answer (score 14):

You are summing up the numbers from 1 to n, incrementing the value by one each time.  This is essentially the classic [Gauss sumation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss#Anecdotes) which is:

```
sum(1 .. n) = (n * n-1)/2
```

This also happens to be the number of times through the loop.

```
(n^2 - n) / 2
(n^2)/2 - n/2
```

When representing [Big O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), only term with the highest power is used and constants are thrown away, and thus the answer is O(n<sup>2</sup>).

More about this particular problem can be read on [CS.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com) at [Big O: Nested For Loop With Dependence](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/4590/big-o-nested-for-loop-with-dependence)

Comment: Well, he is summing the numbers from 1 to n-1, but yes, the concept and everything else is correct.

Answer (score 0):

On the 1st iteration of the outer loop (i = 0), the inner loop will iterate 0 times
On the 2nd iteration of the outer loop (i = 1), the inner loop will iterate 1 time
On the 3rd iteration of the outer loop (i = 2), the inner loop will iterate 2 times

.

.

On the FINAL iteration of the outer loop (i = n ‐ 1), the inner loop will
iterate n ‐ 1 times

So, the total number of times the statements in the inner loop will be executed
will be equal to the sum of the integers from 1 to n ‐ 1, which is:

```
((n ‐ 1)*n) / 2 = (n^2)/2 ‐ n/2 = O(n^2) times
```

Answer (score -1):

if i==0   then  j ranges from 0 to -1  ==> (not possible)  0 
if i==1   then  j ranges from 0 to 0   ==>                 1
if i==2   ,,     ,,             ,, 1   ==>                 2
.
.
.
if i==n-1  then  j from    0 to n-2    ==>                 n-1 iterations

summing them

It is    S = 0   + 1   + 2 + 3 +.......+ n-2  +  n-1
same as  S = n-1 + n-2 + ......        +  1   +   0

summing  2*S= (n-1) + (n-1) +.............(n-1)  //n times

==>  2*S = (n-1)*n
==>  S=    (n-1)*n/2

Answer (score -2):

You can see that it follows a particular equation which is `(n*(n-1))/2`. e,g for n=5, runs=(n*(n-1))/2=5*4/2=10.So it is O(n*(n-1))=O(n^n-n)=O(n^2)[As in case of Big-O, lower order terms and constants are ignored]